# App build not appear in App Store connect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I upload the iOS app to my apple account,

I follow these steps
Product > Archive 
And it opens an Organizer window And i can see my app

so click on it and click Distribute App after following it.
It's telling me Upload success

Like this
[image: Test]

But after going to my app in `https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/` and check to Prepare for Submission and Build section I can't see it also in Activity Tab! It's Empty!

Comment: It would take 20 to 30 minutes to appear. When did you upload the build?

Comment: check your mail.Apple sometimes reject after upload due to some issues.

Comment: @VinayakaSY it's before 1 hour!

Comment: @Dilan I check out it but i don't see an email from Apple!

Comment: @Dilan Now I got the email, it's for `Missing Purpose String in Info.plist` And i add it, So now should i change something else before submitting it again?

Comment: No. As long as you corrected what they've asked of you, you should be fine.

Comment: @MAT xcode tell me to increment build version but i couldn't find it in xcode 11!!

Comment: Look up ```Bundle Version``` in ```plist``` and then plus one.